# Get response as json after a post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't know if this is possible or not. I am working with asp.net mvc3 form. I am posting a form to a action and i want to get the response as json. 
for example-

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { Class = "formValidation", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
<dt>
    <label>
        Ad Image:
    </label>
</dt>    
<dd>
    <input id="bannerImage" name="bannerImage" type="file" class="fileupload" />
</dd>
<dt>
    <label>
        JS Code:
    </label>
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.JsCode, 10, 50, new { })
</dd>

    <input type="submit" class="button red" value="Update Banner" />}
```

This is the form. And after submit I want to do something like

```
public ActionResult Action(Model editModel, HttpPostedFileBase file){
//do something
return Json(new{type="success"});
}
```

Then receive this from the form page and take some action. Is it possible?
if not please can you give me some hints to do this otherwise.

Comment: What action do you want to perform on the page after the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax form instead of Html form. You can subscribe to OnSuccess javascript event and get output in format you like and also in json and process it there.

Comment: Darin, that is the problem. Is there any other alternatives?